# How to download and save a file to local path using php cURL

Tags: php, file, curl, download

I have a URL as following

www.domain.com/file.asp?File=peoples.csv

This URL force downloads the file when hit in browser but i want to download this file on my local path using CURL.

Is there any way, thanks for help

Comment: Please check this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736225/how-to-get-curl-to-save-to-a-different-directory)

Comment: I looking for help in php

Comment: This QUESTION will solve your problem. -[Download&Save File][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522138/download-and-save-a-gzip-file-using-php-curl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, got the solution. Sharing my answer.

```
$getFile = 'http://url to file/file.csv';
$getParams  = array ();

$path = '/var/save/to/local/path/file_name.csv';
$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($getFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if(fwrite($fp,$data))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Thanks all for your help.
Reference :
http://www.technologyworkshops.net/php/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-to-local-path-using-curl-t132.html

Answer (score 3):

May info below helps you.

```
curl your_url >your_file_path
```

and wget may also helps you slove this porblem.
input:

```
wget your_url
```

Comment: I looking for help in php

Comment: You haven't add any tags like 'php'.'CURL' in my mind is just a linux command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `curl URL >file_path`, `curl -o file_path URL`, or `curl -O URL`. The latter command will take the filename from the URL and use it to store the downloaded data.

For example, `curl -O https://example.com/search/clothes.html` will create a *clothes.html* file with the data downloaded from https://example.com/search/clothes.html.